# Convert set to list in Python

Tags: python

I'm converting a set to a list, and then to a string in Python. I can remove the brackets in the string output, but I also want to remove the quotes around the string.

This is what I tried:

```
 instance_list = ec2.describe_instances()
    for reservation in instance_list["Reservations"]:
            for instance in reservation.get("Instances", []):
                tree = objectpath.Tree(instance)
                private_ips =  set(tree.execute('$..PrivateIpAddress'))
                if len(private_ips) == 0:
                    private_ips = None
                if private_ips:
                private_ips_list = list(private_ips)
                private_ips_list = str(private_ips_list).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\','')
               else:
                   public_ips_list = None
```

This is the error I get:

```
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 64
    private_ips_list = str(private_ips_list).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('\','')
                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

If I change the bottom line to this, without the final replace, the script works.

```
private_ips_list = str(private_ips_list).replace('[','').replace(']','')
```

But the quotes are still there:

```
Private IP: '10.48.136.41'
```

How can I remove the quotes from the output?

Comment: An example input/output perhaps?

Comment: This is not a run-time error, it's a syntax error. You have a missing quote somewhere.

Comment: `.replace('\','')` is escaped incorrectly. It should be `'\''`.

Comment: If you want a comma-separated list of set values, do so explicitly; don't abuse `list.__repr__` to do it. `', '.join(private_ips)`.

Comment: I have a feeling that you're looking for [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)... but as it stands, the question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: OK I tried to keep it minimal. So I may have incorrectly omitted the input/output. I'll update the OP with more detail momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
a = set(["Blah", "Hello"])
str1 = ''.join(a)
```